# Can I use third-party libraries with React and TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-bootstrap

I’m trying to setup a new project with React, and I’m thinking in replacing PropTypes with TypeScript.

But I want to know if I’m going to have integration issues.

For example:

- Using Redux (or `react-redux`) with TypeScript + React
- Issues integrating components that are not created with TypeScript
- Problems with libraries like `react-bootstrap`

My main concern is related to importing from TypeScript a non-TypeScript code.

Any clues or experience with this?

Comment: We've used both redux and react-bootstrap with react and typescript and it's all worked really well together. For redux I'd especially recommend this: https://github.com/piotrwitek/typesafe-actions. Using 3rd party components written in plain JS has been no issue for us, especially if you have type definitions for them (which most do), as explained in one of the answers below about DefinitelyTyped.

Answer (score 6):

You can import Javascript libraries in your Typescript project. I do that all the time, unfortunately. Some libraries have community-typed types which you can install by running `npm i @types/mypackage --dev`.

Otherwise, you will have to create an empty TS module declaration for the package:

Adhering to convention, create a file named **mypackage.d.ts** somewhere in your `src` directory. (I usually place it in `src/types/`)

**mypackage.d.ts** should contain `declare module "mypackage";`

Now, whatever you import from the **mypackage** will have type **any**.

Answer (score 2):

well you can use react redux with typescript just you need to install react-redux types:

```
npm install @types/react-redux
```

and types for react-bootstrap :

```
npm install  @types/react-bootstrap
```

but still there is some problem with `FormControl` and `Button` events!

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source organisation called `DefinitelyTyped` which is in charge of adding types to all those libraries that are not TS by default.

In your case if you are using `react-redux`, you might want to install `@types/react-redux` this way.

```
npm install @types/react-redux --dev
```

Check the organisation in Github:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/react-redux

This is only an example they have hundreds of types packages for different libraries.